# Why doesn't Java ME have exception handlers?

Tags: java, java-me, try-catch

I was looking for the differences between Java platforms and i noticed that J2ME does not have exception handlers.

What makes try-catch so heavy that Sun did not include them in Java ME?

Comment: What makes you think that Java ME doesn't have exceptions? It **definitely** has them! Even [CLDC 1.0 has them](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.0/jsr030/java/lang/Exception.html).

Comment: But does it have exception handlers?

Comment: Yes what do you mean?Check here:http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html. A whole list of exceptions

Comment: @eversor:Well if it has defined so many exceptions it would be very odd if there was no way to catch them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about exception handlers such as set by [`Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29), then the reason is simple:

All current Java ME versions are based on pretty old Java SE versions (1.3, I think, but don't quote me on that exact version). And that Java SE version simply didn't have that feature, so they didn't "remove" anything in Java ME in this instance.

Note, also, that those handlers are easily emulated by starting your `Thread` with a `Runnable` that catches all exceptions and handles them as desired, so they are not an irreplaceable API element.